# Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usablee

Tags: javascript, php, image, canvas, kineticjs

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.
```

in this line code it happens:

```
var nodeIconImg = new Image();
                var nodeIcon = new Kinetic.Image({
                  image: nodeIconImg,
                  width: 30,
                  height: 30,
                  cornerRadius: radius
                });
            if(node.main_photo == 'no_photo.png')
            {
                var url = '<?= URL::to(''); ?>/img/' + node.main_photo;
                nodeIconImg.src = url;
            }
```

I'am using kinetic js, the strings are right, the image file exists, but after I assign the src that error happens, can't figure it out, also I've tried this:

```
var url = escape('<?= URL::to(''); ?>/img/' + node.main_photo);
```

but it doesn't helped, any ideas??

what means this error? and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Can you create any jsfiddle demo?

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until image is loaded, before creating `Kinetic.Image` object.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    var image = new Kinetic.Image({
       image : img
    });
}
img.src = 'url';
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/gibeq/1/edit